# Modify DataFrame based on previous row (cumulative sum with condition based on previous cumulative sum result)

Tags: python, pandas, sequential

I have a dataframe with one column containing numbers (quantity). Every row represents one day so whole dataframe is should be treated as sequential data. I want to add second column that would calculate cumulative sum of the quantity column but if at any point cumulative sum is greater than 0, next row should start counting cumulative sum from 0.

I solved this problem using iterrows() but I read that this function is very inefficient and having millions of rows, calculation takes over 20 minutes. My solution below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([-1,-1,-1,-1,15,-1,-1,-1,-1,5,-1,+15,-1,-1,-1], columns=['quantity'])


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        df.loc[index, 'outcome'] = df.loc[index, 'quantity']
    else:
        previous_outcome = df.loc[index-1, 'outcome'] 
        if previous_outcome > 0:
            previous_outcome = 0

        df.loc[index, 'outcome'] = previous_outcome + df.loc[index, 'quantity']

print(df)

#   quantity    outcome
#   -1          -1.0
#   -1          -2.0
#   -1          -3.0
#   -1          -4.0
#   15          11.0 <- since this is greater than 0, next line will start counting from 0
#   -1          -1.0
#   -1          -2.0
#   -1          -3.0
#   -1          -4.0
#   5            1.0 <- since this is greater than 0, next line will start counting from 0
#   -1          -1.0
#   15          14.0 <- since this is greater than 0, next line will start counting from 0
#   -1          -1.0
#   -1          -2.0
#   -1          -3.0
```

Is there faster (more optimized way) to calculate this?

I'm also not sure if the "if index == 0" block is the best solution and if this can be solved in more elegant way? Without this block there is an error since in first row there cannot be "previous row" for calculation.

Comment: Your data is more like an array. Have you tried to look at `numpy` functions? Iterating over `numpy` arrays is much more efficient than iterating over `DataFrame` rows - never do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over `DataFrame` rows is very slow and should be avoided. Working with chunks of data is the way to go with `pandas`.

For you case, looking at your `DataFrame` column `quantity` as a `numpy` array, the code below should speed up the process quite a lot compared to your approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([-1,-1,-1,-1,15,-1,-1,-1,-1,5,-1,+15,-1,-1,-1], columns=['quantity'])

x = np.array(df.quantity)
y = np.zeros(x.size)

total = 0
for i, xi in enumerate(x):
    total += xi
    y[i] = total
    total = total if total < 0 else 0

df['outcome'] = y

print(df)
```

Out :

```
    quantity  outcome
0         -1     -1.0
1         -1     -2.0
2         -1     -3.0
3         -1     -4.0
4         15     11.0
5         -1     -1.0
6         -1     -2.0
7         -1     -3.0
8         -1     -4.0
9          5      1.0
10        -1     -1.0
11        15     14.0
12        -1     -1.0
13        -1     -2.0
14        -1     -3.0
```

If you still need more speed, suggest to have a look at [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) as per jezrael [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69750009/5069105).

## Edit - Performance test

I got curious about performance and did this module with all 3 approaches.

I haven't optimised the individual functions, just copied the code from OP and [jezrael answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69750009/5069105) with minor changes.

```
"""
bench_dataframe.py
Performance test of iteration over DataFrame rows.

Methods tested are `DataFrame.iterrows()`, loop over `numpy.array`,
and same using `numba`.
"""
from numba import njit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def pditerrows(df):
    """Iterate over DataFrame using `iterrows`"""

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if index == 0:
            df.loc[index, 'outcome'] = df.loc[index, 'quantity']
        else:
            previous_outcome = df.loc[index-1, 'outcome'] 
            if previous_outcome > 0:
                previous_outcome = 0

            df.loc[index, 'outcome'] = previous_outcome + df.loc[index, 'quantity']
            
    return df


def nparray(df):
    """Convert DataFrame column to `numpy` arrays."""

    x = np.array(df.quantity)
    y = np.zeros(x.size)

    total = 0
    for i, xi in enumerate(x):
        total += xi
        y[i] = total
        total = total if total < 0 else 0
    
    df['outcome'] = y
    
    return df


@njit
def f(x, lim):
    result = np.empty(len(x))
    result[0] = x[0]

    for i, j in enumerate(x[1:], 1):
        previous_outcome = result[i-1]
        if previous_outcome > lim:
            previous_outcome = 0
        result[i] = previous_outcome + x[i]
    return result

def numbaloop(df):
    """Convert DataFrame to `numpy` arrays and loop using `numba`.
    See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/69750009/5069105]
    """
    df['outcome'] = f(df.quantity.to_numpy(), 0)
    return df

def create_df(size):
    """Create a DataFrame filed with -1's and 15's, with 90% of 
    the entries equal to -1 and 10% equal to 15, randomly 
    placed in the array.
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame(
            np.random.choice(
                (-1, 15), 
                size=size, 
                p=[0.9, 0.1]
            ),
            columns=['quantity'])
    return df


# Make sure all tests lead to the same result
df = pd.DataFrame([-1,-1,-1,-1,15,-1,-1,-1,-1,5,-1,+15,-1,-1,-1],
                  columns=['quantity'])
assert nparray(df.copy()).equals(pditerrows(df.copy()))
assert nparray(df.copy()).equals(numbaloop(df.copy()))
```

Running for a somewhat small array, `size = 20_000`, leads to:

```
In: import bench_dataframe as bd
 .. df = bd.create_df(size=20_000)

In: %timeit bd.pditerrows(df.copy())
7.06 s ± 224 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In: %timeit bd.nparray(df.copy())
9.76 ms ± 710 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In: %timeit bd.numbaloop(df.copy())
437 µs ± 12.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Here `numpy` arrays were 700+ times faster than `iterrows()`, and `numba` was still 22 times faster than `numpy`.

And for larger arrays, `size = 200_000`, we get:

```
In: import bench_dataframe as bd
 .. df = bd.create_df(size=200_000)

In: %timeit bd.pditerrows(df.copy())
I gave up and hit Ctrl+C after 10 minutes or so... =P

In: %timeit bd.nparray(df.copy())
86 ms ± 2.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In: %timeit bd.numbaloop(df.copy())
3.15 ms ± 66.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Making `numba` again 25+ times faster than `numpy` arrays for this example, and confirming that you should avoid at all costs to use `iterrows()` for anything more than a couple of hundreds of rows.

Comment: I tested your solution but there is crucial difference between it's result and my expected result - whenever 'outcome' is greater than 0, I want it to be saved as that value (and not 0). Only the next line should be starting calculation from 0.

In my example data, the first line with quantity = 15 should have outcome = 11. Using your method the outcome = 0

Comment: @Malachiasz - For improve performance in looping solutions need numba, here if use only `enumerate` performance is not nice.

Comment: @Malachiasz all you have to do is to swap the last 2 lines of the for loop... the point was: work with arrays rather than dataframes

Comment: np. Updated answer to have the full code. Please rate questions and mark the ones that fix your case as accepted.

Comment: @jezrael fair point. numba has some overhead due to compilation, so real benefit should show up for much larger arrays. I'll update the benchmark and see =)

Answer (score 0):

I think [**numba**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#using-numba) is the best when working with loops if performance is important:

```
@njit
def f(x, lim):
    result = np.empty(len(x), dtype=np.int)
    result[0] = x[0]

    for i, j in enumerate(x[1:], 1):
        previous_outcome = result[i-1]
        if previous_outcome > lim:
            previous_outcome = 0
        result[i] = previous_outcome + x[i]
    return result

df['outcome1'] = f(df.quantity.to_numpy(), 0)
print(df)
    quantity  outcome  outcome1
0         -1     -1.0        -1
1         -1     -2.0        -2
2         -1     -3.0        -3
3         -1     -4.0        -4
4         15     11.0        11
5         -1     -1.0        -1
6         -1     -2.0        -2
7         -1     -3.0        -3
8         -1     -4.0        -4
9          5      1.0         1
10        -1     -1.0        -1
11        15     14.0        14
12        -1     -1.0        -1
13        -1     -2.0        -2
14        -1     -3.0        -3
```